# RestKit : How to parse the JSON response to NSDictionary without mapping any entity or class?

Tags: ios, restkit

I just want the RestKit to parse the JSON data into `NSDictionary`, but not a class. This is because the attributes of the JSON data is dynamic, means the number of fields is not fixed and field count can be large. So I don't want to create a huge class to map the json data. Just keep that in `NSDictionary`. Does RestKit provide this functionality or we have to work out some other way.Guidance Needed.

Thanks.

Have to modify the Restkit to support the ability ....

Answer (score 1):

RKObjectRequestOperation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData

then parse the json data to dictionary or array

Answer (score 0):

Either use AFNetworking (which RestKit is built on top of) or use a dynamic mapping (depending on your destination class needs).

If you have large arbitrary data then you should just avoid using RestKit as it will only slow your performance.

Comment: so then which framework can be use ? I am fresh on the Restkit, I feeling it is not flexible and a little trouble to use but not sure why so many coder still use it

Comment: RestKit is great, if it does what you need. From your description it doesn't so you should just use AFNetworking.